# Setting Auto Proxy in Force.com IDE behind VPN

Tags: eclipse, proxy, salesforce, force.com

I work remotely, so I always have to connect to COrporate VPN.
I'm having issues with proxy setting that are needed for Force.com IDE.
I was able to access Salesforce.com both sandboxes and production from IE, Chrome or firefox, but not able to connect using force.com IDE/Eclipse.
I tried to check for proxy settings in Internet Options, but all I can see is "Automatically Detect Settings" is selected and nothing else.

I tried calling my company helpdesk and they are asking me to call either Salesforce/Eclipse teams to find what is wrong with it. :)

So not sure how to get proxy host and port details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to “Window –> Preferences”
2. Preferences box prompt out, choose “Network Connections”
3. Select “Manual” from Action Provider drop down list
4. Select Http in the List and click “Edit” button
5. Fill in the proxy server host and port number, (fill in the username and
   password if any)
6. Ok, Done.